# For array copy, does const& perform better?

Tags: c++, performance

For example

```
class A
{
    std::array<int, 10> m_data;

    A(std::array<int, 10> data) : m_data(data) {} // version 1 without const&

    A(std::array<int, 10> const& data) : m_data(data) {} // version 2 with const&
};
```

For the 2 versions, which one performs better?

Comment: Measure and tell us.

Comment: Second should perform better in general because of 1 less copy that it needs to do. Note than even `move` in your case would be same as copy. But again, measure it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Without optimizations, the second version will perform one copy less. The first one copies the object first to pass it into the constructor by value, and then copies the parameter into the field. The second version only performs copying into the field because the parameter is passed by reference.

However, since you declare these constructors inside the class declaration, it is very likely that the compiler will just optimize away the first copy, and maybe sometimes even both of them if the context allows.

Still, the second way is pretty much industry standard. There is no reason to pass something potentially large by value if you can do it by const reference.